# How to Keep Nav bar from shifting when window resized

Tags: css, resize, nav, autoresize

I am new to html/css. My problem is when I re-size my browser window the text of the nav-bar shifts/condenses according to the size of the window and becomes distorted. I would like it to remain static so that when I narrow my browser window I would have to have to scroll over to the right to be able to see the text again. I'm using bootstrap as well.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WINES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GRAPES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

I tried using `.container {width: 900px;}` but that didn't help. The nav bar still doesn't stay static.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by adding a min-width to the navbar.

```
 navigation {        
    margin-right: auto;    
    margin-left: auto;    
    max-width: 100%;    
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer at all? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding a minimum width to a div surrounding the nav bar.

In your case it would be in the .nav class

```
.nav {
   min-width:165px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

I don't know if you shared all the code with us, but from the code you provided 165px should be fine for the minimum width. If there is more code present that makes the navbar a different width then you may need to adjust the pixel amount of `min-width:`.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work and there is no explanation here.